# materializecss modal shows every 24 hours per users

Tags: jquery, html

so i have the following codes :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.modal').modal();

  if ($.cookie('modal') != '1') {
    $('#modal1').modal('open');
    $.cookie('modal', '1', {
      expires: 1
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="modal1" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content center-align">
    <h5>we have special offer for you</h5>
    <div class="row">
      <form class="col s12">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col s4">
            <input placeholder="your name" id="first_name" type="text" class="validate">
          </div>
          <div class="input-field col s4">
            <input id="email" type="email" class="validate" placeholder="your email address">
            <label for="email" data-error="wrong" data-success="right"></label>
          </div>
          <div class="input-field col s4">
            <input placeholder="your phone number" id="first_name" type="text" class="validate">
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#!" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-light btn"><i class="Large material-icons right">send</i>send</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

its shows a modal every time users refresh any page on my website but I wanted to show it once in 24 hours for every user. But it does not work in that way. Can someone point where am I going wrong

Comment: I guess you should know the user's ip address

Comment: Is `$` and `$.cookie` defined? And are you sure the `expires` option needs to be set to `1`?

Comment: yes i guess theyre defined and i change 1 to any number its 1 just for test still its not work correct.